# Angles in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry

Given a vector $v\neq0$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we know that the angles $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ between $v$ and the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis respectively, sum to $\frac{\pi}{2}$; $$\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}=0.$$
One can formulate this by saying that the angles between the axes and a given vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ satisfy the polynomial relation $p_{2}(x,y)=0$ for the polynomial $p_{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\pi)[x,y]$ defined by $p_{2}(x,y)=x+y-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Now my question is how about higher dimensions? That is, given an integer $n\ge3$, does there exist a polynomial $0\neq p_{n}\in\mathbb{Q}(\pi)[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ such that given a vector $0\neq v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the respective angles $\theta_{1},...,\theta_{n}$ between $v$ and the $x_{1},...,x_{n}$-axes satisfy $$p_{n}(\theta_{1},...,\theta_{n})=0?$$

For simplicity in defining the angles, let's say that we restrict ourselves to vectors $v$ with non-negative entries, so that the angle $\theta_{i}$ between $v$ and the $x_{i}$-axis is given by$$\cos\theta_{i}=\frac{\langle v,e_{i}\rangle}{||v||},$$where $e_{i}$ is the $i$-th element of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I think that the right thing to do is to start to think on the case $n=3$.

Thanks!

Comment: Given that angles are defined modulo $2\pi$, a polynomial relation seems highly unlikely to me.

Comment: @Marc, but it works in two dimensions – all the angles are being taken to be between zero and $\pi/2$.

Comment: To follow up on my deleted answer: That there is no non-trivial polynomial relation among the angles if $n \geq 3$ follows almost immediately from the assertion that if $0 < a < 1$, then the function $\theta_{2} = \arccos\sqrt{a^2 - \cos^2\theta_{1}}$ is not algebraic on $(\arccos a, \frac{\pi}{2})$. While I (strongly) believe this is true, I don't have a proof.